# Elasticsearch searchable synthetic fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Provided that in a source document (JSON) exist a couple of fields named, `a` and `b`,
that are of type `long`, I would like to construct a synthetic field (e.g. `c`) 
by concatenating the values of the previous fields with an underscore and 
index it as `keyword`.

That is, I am looking into a feature that could be supported with an imaginary, partial, mapping like this:

```
...

  "a": { "type": "long" },
  "b": { "type": "long" },
  "c": {
    "type": "keyword"
    "expression": "${a}_${b}" 
  },
...
```

**NOTE:** The mapping above was made up just for the sake of the example. It is NOT valid!

So what I am looking for, is if there is a feature in elasticsearch, a recipe or hint to support
this requirement. The field need not be registered in `_source`, just need to be searchable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 steps to this -- a [`dynamic_mapping`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) and an [`ingest_pipeline`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-apis.html).

I'm assuming your field `c` is non-trivial so you may want to match that field in a dynamic template using a [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch)  and assign the `keyword` mapping to it:

```json
PUT synthetic
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "c_like_field": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match":   "c*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "b": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can set up a pipeline which'll concatenate your `a` & `b`:

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/combined_ab
{
  "description" : "Concatenates fields a & b",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "c",
        "value": "{{_source.a}}_{{_source.b}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After ingesting a new doc (with the activated pipeline!)

```json
POST synthetic/_doc?pipeline=combined_ab
{
  "a": 531351351351,
  "b": 251531313213
}
```

we're good to go:

```json
GET synthetic/_search
```

yields

```json
{
  "a":531351351351,
  "b":251531313213,
  "c":"531351351351_251531313213"
}
```

Verify w/ `GET synthetic/_mapping` too.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Just wondering, if "c" is indeed trivial, I suppose I can get away with a simple static mapping (no need for dynamic) and of course the ingestion pipeline. Isn't this true?

Comment: Most definitely!