# Accessing _meta (in _mapping) on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, metadata, kibana, elastic-stack

In my team, the developers store some **information about the fields** of an index **in _meta, inside _mapping**. I need to access this info **from inside kibana** (preferably not using dev tools). Is it possible, and if yes, how?
We use ElasticSearch 6.8.

Answer (score -2):

The `_meta` fields within the mapping are just that -- restricted to the **index** mapping. The docs themselves don't have access to them -- neither in Kibana Discover/Visualize nor in the Dev Tools.

---

What I'd do is fill (periodically update, if required) the individual docs' meta fields using, for example, [`update by query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-example). It's of course data duplication but that's almost inevitable in NOSQL.

Alternatively, if your mapping's meta attributes don't change too often and your indexing approach doesn't include them, you could set up an [ingest pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404331/8160318) which'll update your docs ... upon ingest.

Comment: Thx for ur answer. The developers ALREADY store some information about the fields of an index in _meta, inside _mapping. My question is, how to access this from within Kibana?

Comment: You can't. The only way of doing so is by calling `GET my_index/_mapping`. Also, Visualizations and the Discover Tab in Kibana are predicated upon setting up an index pattern which is based on the **docs**, not the index itself. So there's really no way around it...