# Is it possible to apply a function to a field when making the search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make a `Range` search on a **date** field which is now mapped to **text**. The problem is that there are already data in that field; so it is not a good idea to drop the index and recreate a new `index` to map the field to be `date`. So I thought about applying a custom function to the field to make the `Range` search. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Update documents without the need of dropping and recreating whole index.

If store is enabled for the index, you can create a sub-field with correct data type. For e.g. if the existing field name is `dateText` then you can update index mapping as follows and take advantage of update by query to re-index all your documents.

```
PUT myindex/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "datetext": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "dateField": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"   //<--- change this as per the data
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) after updating the mapping.

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```

Once the above is completed you can use range query on `dateText.dateField`.

**Option 2:** You can use [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) where you have to handle text to date conversion and applying range logic.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly possible using a script query but your text field would either need to have [`fielddata: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) set on it or be of the `.keyword` type (as a [multifield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers), for example) for the script to have access to the field value.

Once that's been taken care of, let's assume your text field `dateFieldAsText` contains epoch timestamps in seconds and you'd want to filter gte & lte with human readable date ranges. We could then parse everything into milliseconds and then do a simple comparison:

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def doc_ts_milli = Integer.parseInt(doc['dateFieldAsText'].value) * 1000L;
          
          def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
          def gte_ts = df.parse(params.gte).getTime();
          def lte_ts = df.parse(params.lte).getTime();
          
          return doc_ts_milli >= gte_ts && doc_ts_milli <= lte_ts
        """,
        "params": {
          "gte": "2020/01/01",
          "lte": "2021/01/01"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The challenge with this is that scripts are reinitialized in each query (unless [they're stored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts)) and are therefore slow. So the best way to go here would be to update the mapping w/ a new date field and then call `_reindex` to [update all docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-scripts). No index dropping required.

Now the issue with this approach is that this won't affect any new, incoming documents. In that case you either modify your ingest process to also include that new date field (so you'd have two fields w/ identical values for legacy reasons) or you establish an ingest pipeline to do that for you (-> no ingest process adjustments needed). Here's an example of [such a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402592/elasticsearch-searchable-synthetic-fields/62404331#62404331), though devised for a slightly different purpose. The principles are the same.