# How to implement "lowercase" in an ElasticSearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement lowercase functionality in ElasticSearch. According to their API docs here

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/lowercase-processor.html
```

you use this code snippet

```
{
  "lowercase": {
   "field": "foo"
  }
}
```

in the query to get a lowercase value contained in the required field.

They do not have a specific example and I keep getting an error when I execute a search query.

This is what I tried:

```
 POST /users/_search
 {
  "size" : 10,
  "_source" : {
   "includes" : [
    "userid",
    "username" 
   ]
  },
  "query" : {
      "query_string" : {
          "query" : "*John*",
           "lowercase": { "default_field" : "username.keyword"}
      }
   },
 "sort" : [
   {
     "_doc" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

In the above query I try to find a username 'john' (converted 'John' to lowercase).

Error message is as follows:

```
{
  "error" : {
   "root_cause" : [
    {
     "type" : "parsing_exception",
     "reason" : "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after 
   [lowercase]",
     "line" : 18,
     "col" : 27
     }
   ],
  "type" : "parsing_exception",
  "reason" : "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after 
[lowercase]",
  "line" : 18,
  "col" : 27
 },
  "status" : 400
 }
```

The same query works (although it does not give me the result that I need) if I replace

```
 "lowercase": { "default_field" : "username.keyword"}
```

with

```
  "default_field" : "username.keyword"
```

Any suggestions about how I can fix this query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processor you're referencing is part of an **ingest pipeline** -- enabling you to transform your data *before* it gets ingested. It has nothing to do with querying data.

You can *simulate* an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html) like so:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "lowercase": {
          "field": "username"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "username": "John"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404331/8160318) to see pipelines in action.

---

As you ingest textual data into Elasticsearch, it gets analyzed and tokenized. The default analyzer is the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and you can see how it'd tokenize the word "John" when you run:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": "John",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

As you can see, it auto-lowercases any input text. This means that when you ingest a single doc into a new index called `indexname`:

```
POST indexname/_doc
{
  "username": "John"
}
```

you can then search lowercase tokens straightaway:

```
GET indexname/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "username",
      "query": "john*"
    }
  }
}
```

As a matter of fact, you don't even need the wildcard `*` at the end.

Comment: did this help @Dennis?